# How to plot different curve in same polar coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, simulation, numerical-methods

I tried to plot the paths of  particle of different sizes in the same polar coordinate using the code given below using matplotlib. The expected plot should be somewhat like this:[image: path of different particle sizes]

Instead I got this plot:
[image: plot for only one value of particle size 1.0e-11m is visible] The trajectories plots for first four particle sizes are invisible as the curves are overlapping. This means the curves are now following the same line. This is clearly seen in the subplots[image: same paths curve]. If the simulation is run separately for different particle sizes they follow different paths as shown: [image: different path for different particles]. It is obvious that the looping is INCORRECT but dont know where and how.

If the particle size 1.0 e-10m the path of the 2.3e-11m particle size alone is visible as below:[image: plot showing the path of only 2.3e-11m particle]. The python code used in the simulations is as given below:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin, cos, pi

# Constants
μ = 379312077e8
R = 60268e3
g_10 = 21141e-9
Ω = 1.7e-4
ρ = 1e3
b_values = [0.95e-10, 0.94e-10, 0.26e-10, 0.25e-10, 0.23e-10, 0.1e-10]
V = 10
ε = 8.85e-12
j_2 = 1.629071e-2

# Function to define the ODEs
def odes(t, p,b):
    r, x, θ, y, ϕ, z = p

# Constants for the given b
    m = (4/3) * pi * (b**3) * ρ
    q = 4 * pi * ε * b * V
    β = q / m

# Other constants
    μ_0 = 4 * pi * 1e-7
    B_θ = (μ_0 / (4 * pi)) * (R / r)**3 * g_10 * sin(θ)
    B_r = (μ_0 / (4 * pi)) * 2 * (R / r)**3 * g_10 * cos(θ)

# Defining the ODEs
    drdt = x
    dxdt = r * (y**2 + (z + Ω)**2 * sin(θ)**2 - β * z * sin(θ) * B_θ) - (μ / r**2) * (1 - (3/2) * j_2 * (R / r)**2 * (3 * cos(θ)**2 - 1))
    dθdt = y
    dydt = (-2 * x * y + r * (z + Ω)**2 * sin(θ) * cos(θ) + (β * r * z * sin(θ) * B_r)) / r + (3 * μ / r**2) * j_2 * (R / r)**2 * sin(θ) * cos(θ)
    dϕdt = z
    dzdt = (-2 * (z + Ω) * (x * sin(θ) + r * y * cos(θ)) + (β * (x * B_θ - r * y * B_r)) / (r * sin(θ)))

    return np.array([drdt, dxdt, dθdt, dydt, dϕdt, dzdt])
 # Define the event function
def event_func(t, p,b):
    return p[0] - R

event_func.terminal = True
event_func.direction = -1

# Time window
t_span = (0, 1000)
t = np.linspace(t_span[0], t_span[1], 1001)

# Initial conditions
r0 = 1.12 * R
p0 = np.array([1.12 * R, 0.0, 90.0 * (pi / 180), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0203 * (pi / 180)])

# Create a figure with a polar projection
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})

# Define colors for plotting
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'm', 'y', 'k']

# Iterate through different values of b
for b, color in zip(b_values, colors):
    
# Solve IVP for the current value of b
    sol = solve_ivp(odes, t_span, p0, args=(b,), t_eval=t,events=(event_func,), method="DOP853",
                dense_output=True, vectorized=False, atol=1e-4, rtol=1e-5)

    # Extract r and ϕ values
    r = sol.y[0, :]
    ϕ = sol.y[4, :]

    # Plot r against ϕ for the current value of b
    ax.plot(ϕ, r, label=f'b = {b:.2e}', color=color)

# Set radial limits
ax.set_rmax(1.5 * R)

# Set radial ticks
ax.set_rticks([R, 1.12 * R, 1.18 * R, 1.2 * R, 1.3 * R])

# Add a circle at the center
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), R, transform=ax.transData._b, facecolor='yellow',
                fill=True, edgecolor='red', linewidth=0.5, zorder=2, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_artist(circle)

# Set plot title and legend
ax.set_title("Polar Plot of r vs Azimuthal Angle (ϕ)")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Why on running the simulation for different sizes changes the paths to circular ones?**

Comment: I'm getting lots of overflow warnings when I run your code, have you tried converting your units so that more of your numbers are of order unity?

Comment: @ AJ Biffl, the overflow could be the vision by zero for r when going to zero. to avoid that event function are added in it. Aslo, for sin and cos, for some initial values the it began with zero. but to avoid this, radian is used. Since there are tow extremes, e-10 and e8, convertion leads to one going almost to infinity.

Comment: No, I was fiddling with the constants, my bad. Not a big deal. And your `event_func` keeps `r` from getting below `R`. It appears the differences between the trajectories are very small, but nonzero. Try plotting `r` vs `phi` on a normal plot and zoom in - very wacky results, but that's not from your code, it's from your model.